# How do I set the privacy for a single pic/photo in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, facebook-photos

I want to restrict viewing of one of my single uploaded pic on Facebook. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Photo permissions are set on an album basis.  You need to put the photo in its own album, or in an album with other photos that you want to have the same permissions, and set the permissions on that album (Account » Privacy Settings » Customize settings » Edit privacy settings for existing photo albums and videos).

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon your question while searching for a similar kind of activity on my timeline picture in facebook. You can go to the picture and hit the edit button and choose custom.

There you will get 2 options - "share this with" and "Don't share this with". Go to the latter and manually enter the names of people whom you wish to exclude. Then, hit "save changes" > "Done editing".

There is another way, you can group them in a single list of people for minimal notifications sharing, so that you can restrict them from viewing your posts in future without manually entering names each time. Hope this helps all, who are wandering for a solution like I did.