# One album managed to have different privacy per photo in a Facebook album - how do I replicate this?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I've always understood that the privacy settings for photos in an album are set on the album not on the individual photo (as is covered [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12914/how-do-i-set-the-privacy-for-a-single-pic-photo-in-facebook)). However, I notice that I have one folder (created by Bitstrips) which has the album privacy setting as "You can change the audience for each photo in this album" and sure enough I am able to set difference settings for the people who can see each photo in that album.

My question is, how do I get other photo albums like this?